# Checkbox Event not trigerred in Listview UWP

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

I'm actually developping an UWP app who's reading Excel data, and display it on a form. Every Excel sheet are represented with RadioButton, and when the user click on a RadioButton, I update a ListView with the corresponding data. 
Every item of the ListView have different data, and 2 checkboxes. This checkboxes can have the state "true" or "false", and if the user need to change the state, I want to modify his value

But the problem is, there is no event triggered with all the checkboxes when I check them. I tried to search and try to make my own template, but without success.

All the data are stored in a class :

```
public class REFERENCES
{
    public int AI_ID { get; set; }
    public int ID_poste { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public string designation { get; set; }
    public bool avance { get; set; }
    public bool jour { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public REFERENCES(int ai_id, int id_poste, string ref_, string des_, string avance_, string jour_)
    {
        AI_ID = ai_id;
        ID_poste = id_poste;
        reference = ref_;
        designation = des_;
        if(jour_ != null)
        {
            jour = true;
        }
        else
        {
            jour = false;
        }
        if (avance_ != null)
        {
            avance = true;
        }
        else
        {
            avance = false;
        }
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

And this is my ListView :

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewData" SelectionMode="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="412" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="650" Margin="0,218,0,0" >
        <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="35" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"  >
                    <TextBlock Text="AI_ID" Width="0" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Désignations" FontSize="20" Width="300" Foreground="Blue" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Références" FontSize="20" Width="150" Foreground="Blue" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Avance" FontSize="20" Width="100" Foreground="Blue" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Jour" FontSize="20" Width="100" Foreground="Blue" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="ExcelLinkData:REFERENCES">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <TextBlock Name="ItemAI_ID" Text="{x:Bind AI_ID}" Width="0" />
                    <TextBlock Name="ItemDesignation" Text="{x:Bind designation}" Width="300" FontSize="16" Height="55" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="ItemReference" Text="{x:Bind reference}" Width="150" FontSize="16" Height="55" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" />
                    <Grid Width="100" Height="55" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <CheckBox Name="ItemAvance" IsChecked="{x:Bind avance}" Tag="{x:Bind AI_ID}" Checked="CHANGE_STATUS_REFERENCE"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Width="100" Height="55" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <CheckBox Name="ItemJour" IsChecked="{x:Bind jour}" Tag="{x:Bind AI_ID}" Checked="CHANGE_STATUS_REFERENCE"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

The method "CHANGE_STATUS_REFERENCE" is the method where I want to change the state in my class.

I tried different solutions, but I'm not an expert in UWP, so if anyone got an advice, I'll take it !

Thanks in advance for your time !

Guillaume

Comment: Change this `IsChecked="{x:Bind jour}"` to `IsChecked="{x:Bind jour Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: @fhnaseer WOW ! Exactly what I needed ! Thank you so much for the reactivity !!!

Comment: UWP binding is a little bit different from WPF. I also faced this few weeks  back,

Comment: I didn't know that "Mode" had this effect.. I'm new in UWP, so binding element is a whole new thing !
I was stuck with this, it was the main objective of my application, so thanks again @fhnaseer

Comment: I added answer below. You can mark the answer as correct to close the question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP, default mode for `Binding` is `OneTime`. And when you change property from viewmodel then no event is triggered. By changing `Binding` to `OneWay` / `TwoWay` (depending on your usage), viewmodel will trigger the event.

Change

```
IsChecked="{x:Bind jour}"
```

To

```
IsChecked="{x:Bind jour Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 <CheckBox Name="ItemAvance" IsChecked="{x:Bind avance}" Tag="{x:Bind AI_ID}" Checked="CHANGE_STATUS_REFERENCE"/>
```

to

```
<CheckBox Name="ItemAvance" IsChecked="{x:Bind avance}" Tag="{x:Bind AI_ID}" Command="{Binding CHANGE_STATUS_REFERENCE}"/>
```

Add a "Flip Function" to your class:

```
private void Flip()
{
    this.avance = !this.avance;
}
```

Set up a RelayCommand:

```
RelayCommand _flipCommand = new RelayCommand(this.Flip);
```

and Implement CHANGE_STATUS_REFERENCE as an [ICommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand?view=netframework-4.7.2) like so:

```
public ICommand CHANGE_STATUS_REFERENCE
{
    get
    {
        return _flipCommand;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'll try to make it this way too !
I'm looking about RelayCommand, but I'm not sure to understand, is it to manage better the event fired when I check (in my case for example) ?